# Discord bot that allows members to assign roles to other members

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm VERY new to coding in JavaScript and I'm trying to create a very simple bot for an event I'm planning in a Discord server.

Basically all it should do is assign a role to a mentioned member (only the first member) if the mentioned member doesn't have a role set in an array.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const ignoredRoles = ["Overseer, Staff, Bots"],
    mutedRole = "Dead";
client.on('ready', () => { console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`) });
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!kill")) {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!member)
            return message.channel.send('You forgot to mention who to kill');
        if (member.roles.find(r => ignoredRoles.includes(r.name)))
            return message.channel.send(`${member.toString()} is not participating in the event!`);
        if (member.roles.find(r => r.name == mutedRole))
            return message.channel.send(`${member.toString()} user is already dead!`);
        member.roles.add(mutedRole)
        message.channel.send(`${member.toString()} has been eliminated!`);
    }
});
client.login('token.env');
```

While the code itself doesn't throw any errors (the bot logs in and it prints the ready state), any time I attempt to summon the bot it does absolutely nothing. I don't think my skill is good enough to figure this out on my own, so any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do this in 4 steps:

`Step 1(Get user and ID at the same time):`

```js
//this'll fetch the first user mentioned, ".id" will return user's id
let member = message.mentions.users.first().id;
```

`Step 2(Fetch the role):`

```js
//replace [Role ID] by role's actual ID.
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "[Role ID]");
```

`Step 3:(Check if user has a role)`

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.find(role)){
  //user is having role, tell them that they already have the role.
}
```

`Step 4:(Add role to member, continue this after step 3)`

```js
else{
  // Add role to the member
  member.roles.add(role);
}
```

Final Code:

```js
let member = message.mentions.users.first().id;
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "[Role ID]");

if (message.member.roles.cache.find(role)){
  //user is having role, tell them that they already have the role.
} else {
  // Add role to the member
  member.roles.add(role);
}
```

Please check [discord.js official docs](https://discordjs.guide), you can find everything related to discord.js there.

Comment: I tried implementing the code you sent here but it seems to be outdated. It didn't work because of the **.some**. Maybe it was discontinued for the Discord.JS v13? Regardless, I kind of got the code working now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Maybe, because I no longer use v12 so IDK.

Comment: Btw i just updated it, if it works then please mark it as answer.